# Как можно воспользоваться пользовательскими переменными в Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть несколько MariaDB SQL скриптов. В них устанавливаются переменные для запросов. Теперь проект будет использовать Oracle БД.

Вот фрагмент из MariaDB SQL скрипта:

```
SET @date_start := '2000-01-01';
SET @date_end := '2001-01-01';
SELECT * FROM user WHERE birth BETWEEN @date_start AND @date_end;
```

И не смог найти ничего подобного в Oracle SQL. Уже попробовал `DECLARE`, `DEFINE`, `WITH`, но не смог получить рабочее решение.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to use a local variable in oracle SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66009847) от участника [@rafaelvol](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13211914/rafaelvol)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66009847

Answer (score 2):

В Oracle SQL нет выражения `SET`. Для того чтобы воспользоваться пользовательскими переменными, как в MariaDB, необходимо использовать переменные в пакетах PL/SQL:

```
create table t as
    select date'2021-01-01'+rownum dt from dual connect by level<=30
/
create or replace package parampack as
    startDate date;
    endDate date;
end;
/

exec parampack.startDate := date'2021-01-30'; parampack.endDate := date'2021-01-31';

var rc refcursor
begin
    open :rc for 
        select * from t
        where dt between parampack.startDate and parampack.endDate;
end;
/
DT
-------------------
2021-01-30 00:00:00
2021-01-31 00:00:00
```

Хотя, если надо просто параметризовать один запрос, то можно использовать однострочный запрос в CTE:

```
with parameters as (
    select date'2021-01-30' startDate, date'2021-01-31' endDate from dual
)
select dt
from t, parameters
where dt between parameters.startDate and parameters.endDate;
/
DT
-------------------
2021-01-30 00:00:00
2021-01-31 00:00:00
```